# Make an array of matrices in Python (numpy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to create an undefined length array of matrices for a neural network, but, when i append the second matrix to the array, the format is messed up.

```
    def createRandomWeights(X):
    initialW = generateWeights(X.shape[1], S[0]) # first weight matrix
    w = np.array([initialW])              # array of weight matrices
    for i in range(0, L - 1):
        layerW = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (S[i], S[i + 1]))
        w = np.append(w, [layerW])
    return w
```

The function generateWeights only creates an NxM size np.matrix of random numbers between -1 and 1.
S is an array of numbers
L is the lenght of S

Example:

```
S = [2,3]
L = len(s)
X = [[1,1,1],[1,-1,1],[-1,1,1],[-1,-1,1]]
```

Expected output example (random numbers wrote as 'rn'):

```
matrix1 = [[rn, rn],[rn, rn],[rn, rn]] # 3x2 matrix
matrix2 = [[rn, rn, rn],[rn, rn, rn]] # 2x3 matrix
output = [matrix1, matrix2] # 2 matrix elements array
```

Real output:

```
output = [rn, rn, rn, rn, rn...] #12 times
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `np.append` instead of using the `append` method for list in Python.

```
def createRandomWeights(X):
    initialW = generateWeights(X.shape[1], S[0]) # first weight matrix
    w = np.array([initialW])              # array of weight matrices
    for i in range(0, L - 1):
        layerW = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (S[i], S[i + 1]))
        w.append(layerW)
    return w
```

The code above should do the job. If you check the docs on [`np.append`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) you will see that it will turn the arguments into a 1 dimensional array if no other params are specified.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also, i had to initialize w as [] and then use w.append with every element.